# how to use regular expression/ beanshell post processor extractor for extracting data from response

Tags: regex, jmeter, beanshell

I have this reponse in the View tree listener

> "__v":0,"language":"en","jobTitle":"Executive","firstName":"wer","lastName":"wre","email":"fde+98989@gmail.com","phone":"+1
>   213-321-3232","_companyId":"5723erera8b2196fdaer9502b86dc7","accountStatus":"UNVERIFIED","role":"ADMIN","emailActivationSecret":"XD1EererreQyVLFn1IjJg7QQNcDz9RLZ1xrKnl84XI5Nb5","_id":"5723a8b21er96fwereeda9ewree502b86dc8","products":[],"created":"2016-04-29T18:32:18.700Z"}

Now, i need to extract the `email`, `email activation secret` and `id` in to this link:

> webserver-wat:3001/activateAccount?email=fde%298989%40gmail.com&secret=XD1EererreQyVLFn1IjJg7QQNcDz9RLZ1xrKnl84XI5Nb5&companyId=5723a8b21er96fwereeda9ewree502b86dc8

And send a post request inorder to activate the link. Is there any way of doing it? Would really appreciate as this is hindering our automation process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it would be easier for you to use [JSON Path Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) (available via [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/)) as this way you will be able to easily parse multiline data, use conditional selectors and JSON Path expressions look much more friendly and human-readable than regex.

For instance:

1. To extracting a single value, i.e. `email` use the following JSON Path Extractor configuration:

   - Destination Variable Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `email`
   - JSON Path Expression: `$.email`
   - Refer extracted value as `${email}` where required
   - Repeat above steps (use  separate JSON Path Extractor) for other dynamic variables
2. If you want everything in a single shot:

   - Destination Variable Name: any suitable variable name, i.e. `param`
   - JSON Path Expression: `$.[email, emailActivationSecret, _id]`
   - Refer extracted values as:

     - `${param_1}` - for "email"
     - `${param_2}` - for "emailActivationSecret"
     - `${param_3}` - for "_id"

References:

- [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) (scroll down to "Parsing JSON")
- [JSONPath - XPath for JSON](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/)
- [JSONPath Online Evaluator](http://jsonpath.com/)

Answer (score 0):

the regex:

```
/.*"email":"(.*?)".*emailActivationSecret":"(.*?)".*"_id":"(.*?)".*/
```

the replacement string:

`"webserver-wat:3001/activateAccount?email=$1&secret=$2&companyId=$1"`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/mK3zR7/3)

Comment: Thank you. In the second request, in the server name: i kept webserver-wat:3001/activateAccount?email=$1&secret=$2&companyId=$1  path : {Activ_url} and method:Post  i get the following error: java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected closing bracket for IPv6 address at index 26: http://[webserver-wat:3001/activateAccount?email=$1&secret=$2&companyId=$1]:8081/error
 at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2829)
 at java.net.URI$Parser.failExpecting(URI.java:2835)
 at java.net.URI$Parser.parseServer(URI.java:3212)

Comment: The post data says this :POST http://[webserver-wat:3001/activateAccount]:8081/error

Comment: the problem iis email should be in this format: email=vdtfddb%2B343243244%40gmail.com (for vdtddb+3434..@gmail.com) i wrote this expression /.*"email":"(.+?)+(.+?)@(.+?)".*emailActivationSecret":"(.*?)".*"_id":"(.*?)".*/      amd the template webserver-wat:3001/activateAccount?email=$1$%4$2$%40$3$&secret=$4&companyId=$5.   and i also need to pass some variables in the activation link inorder to activate the account. I do not understand why this is not working